# #1054 - Unknown column while the column is present

Tags: mysql, sql

My query is not working I don't know why.

Unknown column error showed up when ever I run:

```
SELECT `comitee_member`.*, `comitees`.`Total_Amount`
FROM (`comitee_member`)
INNER JOIN `comitees` c ON `c`.`Id`=`comitee_member`.`Cid` AND c.Status=0     
WHERE `comitee_member`.`Mid` = '3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've aliased the table:

```
INNER JOIN `comitees` c
```

You also need to alias references to the table:

```
SELECT `comitee_member`.*, c.`Total_Amount`
```

As far as the query parser is concerned when it's examining the `SELECT` clause, there is no `comitees` table in the table list.  Only a `comitee_member` table and a `c` table.